# How to convert from blob URL to binary?

Tags: react-admin

I'm using ImageInput component inside an iterator to upload images in my create form and it generates a structure like this:

```
"data": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "test",
            "subTitle": "test",
            "additionalAttributes": {
                "price": "3452345"
            },
            "images": [
                {
                    "src": {
                        "rawFile": {
                            "path": "test.jpg"
                        },
                        "src": "blob:https://localhost:44323/82c04494-244a-49eb-9d0e-6bca5a3469f7",
                        "title": "test.jpg"
                    },
                    "title": "d"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "contact": {
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "jobTitle": "test",
        "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
        "phoneNumber": "23234"
    },
    "theme_id": 1,
    "endDate": "2020-06-19T22:27:00.000Z",
    "status": "2"
}
```

}

What I'm trying to do is sending the image to an API for saving in a folder. Blob URL is an internal object in the browser son it can't be used in the API, so I tried to convert the Blob URL into a binary and send to API.

Following the tutorial I can not get the expected result. Here is my code:

I created a new dataProvider like this:

```
export const PrivateEventProvider = {
  create: (resource: string, params: any) => {
    convertFileToBase64(params.data.items[0].images[0].src.src).then(
        transformedPicture => {
            console.log(`transformedPicture: ${transformedPicture}`);
        }
    );

    const convertFileToBase64 = (file: { rawFile: Blob }) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;

            reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
        });
```

And I have this error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on
>   'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lupG.png)

So my question is, which is the correct way of uploading images to a folder using react-admin?